# Weird Bug in OneDrive gives incorrect folder size

Tags: onedrive

I've added an image that shows two files totaling 2.8 MB. However, OneDrive displays the folder size as 5.0 MB.

This isn't the only folder it does it for and it regularly displays a size that's not exact, but close, such as 128 GB when the real size is 126 GB. What's going on in the background?

[image]

Comment: Onedrive stores metadata in addition to the file. Unsure what size to expect for their metadata, but I expect it to have a base minimum size. Perhaps this is what you are seeing.

Comment: So is this question only about OneDrive-the-website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint to the reason may be found in the bug-report
 [Bug: OneDrive size is being calculated wrong #10001](https://github.com/files-community/Files/issues/10001)
in the answer by the developer cinqmilleans from
October 2022:

> There is a logic to this behavior. OneDrive uses a folder placed by default in the C: drive.
> The sizes displayed therefore correspond to the drive that hosts the folder synchronized with OneDrive. However, the expected, intuitive behavior is to display the remote sizes. This requires code to retrieve these values. It appears that this code does not currently exist for any cloud provider.

This means that the sizes you see are a mixture of the sizes of the
local files and folders with those on the remote server.

I can't say which size is local and which is remote, but if this is
the problem then don't expect an exact correspondence.
The file-systems on the local and remote computers may be quite
different.